# Запрос на выборку 2х товаров для каждого бренда

Tags: sql

Есть таблица товаров, в ней есть поле "бренд".

Нужно выбрать по 2 товара каждого бренда. Помогите написать запрос на выборку товаров.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: пронумеруйте и отфильтруйте.

Comment: Приложите архитектуру таблиц, те запросы, которые пробовали писать

Comment: Здесь есть решения: http://www.sql-ex.ru/help/select16.php

Comment: @SergeyMoiseenko ваша статья что ли? заметьте, вариант с `rank` не в тему вообще в данной задаче, он может выдавать одинаковые значения, так что использовать надо `row_number` для этих целей/

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо @SergeyMoiseenko. Не до конца понял логику, но работает.

```html
SELECT pr1.*, COUNT(*) FROM products pr1
JOIN products  pr2
ON pr1.brand_id = pr2.brand_id AND pr1.id >= pr2.id
GROUP BY pr1.id, pr1.brand_id
HAVING COUNT(*) <=2
ORDER BY brand_id, id
```